# Batch Apex Limits in a trigger

Tags: trigger, batch

In the trailhead lesson "Use Batch Apex" the final line states:

> Use extreme care if you are planning to invoke a batch job from a trigger. You must be able to guarantee that the trigger won't add more batch jobs than the limit.

As far as I can see, the limit for concurrent batch processes is 5.

However when I run the following code in order to try and run more than 5 batch processes concurrently, it appears to automatically queue jobs so that the max number running at any time is 5. So - my question - what do you have to do to add more batch jobs than the limit in a trigger and break it?

```
public class BatchTest {

public static void triggerTest(){
    List<String> stringList = new List<String>{'hello'};
    for(integer i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        Integer runningBatchJobs = [SELECT count() FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE JobType = 'BatchApex' AND status IN ('Queued', 'Processing', 'Preparing')];
        BatchTestBatch batchObject = new BatchTestBatch(stringList);
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchObject, 1);        
    }   
} }
```

batchClass :

```
global class  BatchTestBatch implements Database.Batchable<String>{
private List<String> idList;

public BatchTestBatch(List<String> newIdList){
    idList = newIdList;
}
global Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return idList;
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<String> scope){
    for(integer i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        test__c[] myTest = [SELECT name FROM test__c]; 
    }
    Integer runningBatchJobs = [SELECT count() FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE JobType = 'BatchApex' AND status IN ('Queued', 'Processing', 'Preparing')];
    System.debug(runningBatchJobs);
    System.debug('hi');
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    System.debug(' finished');
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now also the [Flex Queue](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_apex_flex_queue_ga.htm) that allows up to 100 extra jobs to be submitted and kept in a holding status until one of the 5 concurrent slots is available.

So to "break it" you need to add 5 + 100 + 1 jobs in your test.

Answer (score 2):

> Use extreme care if you are planning to invoke a batch job from a
>   trigger. You must be able to guarantee that the trigger won't add more
>   batch jobs than the limit

Implies the daily AsyncApexLimit for Jobs like future,queuabale,scheduler and batch. You can only have 250K a day, if you add more they would be denied.

[image]

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: Plus, each batch will use at least 3 async limits if even one value is returned from start.